# Python: Ogg/Speex Audio Playback?

Tags: python, audio, ogg, speex

Is there a module that supports audio playback for Ogg/Speex (not Ogg/Vorbis) encoded files from within Python 2.6 on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far it seems that the VLC Python bindings are the easiest solution for me. For 64bit Python I downloaded the nightly build executable.

http://wiki.videolan.org/Python_bindings